# Am I really returning address or reference to a temporary

Tags: c++, generics

I am implementing a generic function that finds minimum in an array. It works fine and looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto FindMinimum(T &input, int size) -> decltype(input[0])
{
    auto TempMin=input[0];
    int leastIndex=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if(input[i]<TempMin)
        {
            leastIndex=i;
            TempMin=input[i];
        }
    }

    return TempMin;
}
```

But in the IDE, I get a warning: `returning address or reference to a temporary` . If I change `TempMin` to `input[leastIndex]`, then the warning disappears.

I am wondering that I tend to return by value and also I haven't used `&` anywhere, but why does it still return by reference or address?

Thoughts?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

In `decltype(input[0])`, I have passed a subscript to input array. So shouldn't it really correspond to a value and not a reference or address to a temporary?

Comment: Hint: what's `decltype(input[0])`?

Comment: @hvd  Ohh.. wouldn't it be an integer (if I pass an integer array) as I have given 0 in the subscript of it? so it should correspond to a value? or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "Effective Modern C++" says:

> In C++11, perhaps the primary use for decltype is declaring function
>   templates where the function’s return type depends on its parameter
>   types. For example, suppose we’d like to write a function that takes a
>   container that supports indexing via square brackets (i.e., the use of
>   “[] ”) plus an index, then authenticates the user before returning the
>   result of the indexing operation. The return type of the function
>   should be the same as the type returned by the indexing operation.
>
> **operator[] on a container of objects of type T typically returns a T&.**
>   This is the case for std::deque, for example, and it’s almost always
>   the case for std::vector. For std::vector, however, operator[] 
>   does not return a bool&. Instead, it returns a brand new object ...**but
>   what’s important here is that the type returned by a container’s opera
>   tor[]  depends on the container.**

So this code:

```
template<typename T>
auto FindMinimum(T &input, int size) -> decltype(input[0])
```

`auto` maybe T&.

And this code:

```
auto temp = input[0]
```

`auto` maybe T.

I think the compiler hints you, maybe that's the reason.